# Clearing a "choices dropdown" using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, choices.js

I have a single select dropdown uses the choices library that includes a remove button and displays a variety of cities:
[image: example of drop down]

It's declared in the code as:

```
<select class="cities-dd" placeholder="Select city:" style="font-size:16px;line-height:24px;font-weight:regular;color:#757575;width:350px;vertical-align:middle;">
     <option value="">Select city:</option>`
          for(let city of cities){
               if (city.length>2){
                   tab += `<option value="${city}">${city}</option>`;
                      }};  
</select>
```

I would like to clear the selected city using jQuery.  I have tried a bunch of things including clicking the removeItemButton using:

```
jQuery(".choices__button, input[type='button']").click();
```

and changing the value to null via

`jQuery(".cities-dd").val("").trigger("change");`

but nothing seems to be working.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices this plugin?

Comment: Can we get a working snippet - with rendered HTML?

Comment: @KiranShahi yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [documentation](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices#setup), I found that they have few methods to clear the selected values like `clearChoices()`, `removeActiveItems()`. Luckily, non of these works [see this issue in github](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices/issues/606) and I found a hack in your case. They have a method called `setChoiceByValue(value)` which is used to set the active element. In your case you have a placeholder option called Select city: with value `""`. So, what you can do is set it as a selected item by `setChoiceByValue("");`

See the following example:

```js
console.warn = () => {};

const choices = new Choices($('.cities-dd')[0]);

$("#clear").off("click").on("click", function() {
  console.log(choices.getValue(true));
  choices.setChoiceByValue("");
  console.log(choices.getValue(true));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js/public/assets/scripts/choices.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js/public/assets/styles/choices.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="cities-dd" placeholder="Select city:" style="font-size:16px;line-height:24px;font-weight:regular;color:#757575;width:350px;vertical-align:middle;">
  <option value="">Select city:</option>
  <option value="London">London</option>
  <option value="Birmingham">Birmingham</option>
</select>
<button id="clear">
Clear
</button>
```